# MKAnnotation - adding url

Tags: iphone, url, mkannotation

I'm working through mayurbirari's sample code to generate a mapkit view, I want to add a url to the popup.  I've tried to understand the apple reference to subclass but TBH it just isnt going it.

I need to create a subclass that can have additional variable added to it as MKANNOTATION is core file and cannot be changed - therefore how do I do it?? I'm confused about how to set it up.

the code can be found here --> http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/

if someone could show me the example of the subclass with URL added to it, it would probably sink in, but all the examples I've found seem to be over complicated.

Answer (score 0):

MKAnnotation is a protocol that you have to adopt in your own class -- whichever class you're using to represent an annotation object. This is often a class that's part of your data model. For example, you might have a Person class and want to show instances of Person on a map. You'd adopt MKAnnotation in Person. It's easy to use properties for this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
   //...
}
//...
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subtitle;
@end
```

And then implement the methods from MKAnnotation in your class:

```
@implementation Person

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;

//...various methods of Person...

@end
```

Now you can add instances of Person to the map as annotations.